# Handling safe in node mysql error

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a method in my app.js which handles a get request and makes a mysql query. When everything goes right it is a happy ending but if anything goes wrong, I get similar message.

```
/Users/916784/Documents/Mobile Training/Node_Ex/SimpleAPI/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:78
    throw err;
    ^

Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'undefined' in 'where clause'
at Query.Sequence._packetToError (/Users/916784/Documents/Mobile Training/Node_Ex/SimpleAPI/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:48:14)
at Query.ErrorPacket (/Users/916784/Documents/Mobile Training/Node_Ex/SimpleAPI/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:83:18)
at Protocol._parsePacket (/Users/916784/Documents/Mobile Training/Node_Ex/SimpleAPI/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:280:23)
at Parser.write (/Users/916784/Documents/Mobile Training/Node_Ex/SimpleAPI/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:73:12)
at Protocol.write (/Users/916784/Documents/Mobile Training/Node_Ex/SimpleAPI/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/916784/Documents/Mobile Training/Node_Ex/SimpleAPI/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:96:28)
at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:146:16)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:110:10)
--------------------
at Protocol._enqueue (/Users/916784/Documents/Mobile Training/Node_Ex/SimpleAPI/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:141:48)
at Connection.query (/Users/916784/Documents/Mobile Training/Node_Ex/SimpleAPI/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:201:25)
at /Users/916784/Documents/Mobile Training/Node_Ex/SimpleAPI/routes/routes.js:27:22
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/916784/Documents/Mobile Training/Node_Ex/SimpleAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/Users/916784/Documents/Mobile Training/Node_Ex/SimpleAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
at Route.dispatch (/Users/916784/Documents/Mobile Training/Node_Ex/SimpleAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/916784/Documents/Mobile Training/Node_Ex/SimpleAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at /Users/916784/Documents/Mobile Training/Node_Ex/SimpleAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
at Function.process_params (/Users/916784/Documents/Mobile Training/Node_Ex/SimpleAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
at next (/Users/916784/Documents/Mobile Training/Node_Ex/SimpleAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
```

Of course I know why this error came but I want to handle it safely. Currently my code is

```
app.get('/deleteInventoryItem', function(req, res){
console.log('requested for deleting inventory item with id: ' + req.query.item_id);

if(req.query.item_id){
  app.connection.query('UPDATE ITEMS.ITEMS_TABLE SET item_isdeleted=1 WHERE id=' + req.query.item_id,
    function(err, rows){
      if(err){
        console.log('error occured in deleting: code - ' + err.code + " ,isFatal - " + err.fatal);
        next(err);
      }
      res.send({"status": "success", 
        "message": "Item deleted with id - " + req.query.item_id });
  });
} else{
  res.send({"status": "error", "message": "missing a parameter"});
}
});
```

Here is where I have written the code for next

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
 res.status(500).send({ error: 'Something failed!' });
});
```

How can I handle the error part so that my **node.js server doesnt crash**?
How can I send apt response instead of sending the entire error stack trace

Comment: i recommend to use parametrized query and a validator module

Comment: Are you using Express.js for your server?

Comment: I would suggest not `throw`ing an error. This is from the [nodejs docs](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html) "Any use of the JavaScript throw mechanism will raise an exception that must be handled using try / catch or the Node.js process will exit immediately."

Comment: How to use parameterized query? I am using express.js only..

Comment: @Mani, did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @Mani were you able to find anything here? I have same problem, I have express, I have MySQL, MySQL rethrow is crashing the app even error handler is in place. I know how to fix error but if there is any runtime error, I don't want app to crash

Answer (score 2):

Based on the stacktrace I noticed you're using Express.js. This gives you some options to handle internal errors.

First it's recommended to define some fallback [error handler middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) like this:

```
app.use(function(error, request, response, next) {
    console.log("Error handler: ", error);

    // Send an error message to the user.
    response.status(500).json({error:error.message});

    // Optionally log the request options so you can analyze it later.
});
```

Whenever you encounter an error while processing your request, you can forward this error by using the `next` argument that is passed along to your middleware, e.g.:

```
app.get("/throw", function(request, response, next) {
    var error = new Error("Express.js will delegate this error to the error handler.");
    next(error);
});
```

Comment: I have followed the same but now the response sent back to client is weird. I get " Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column &#39;undef&#39; in &#39;where clause&#39;<br> &nbsp; &nbsp; << too long, contains stacktrace>> "
I have used res.status(500);
  res.render('error', { error: err });

Comment: What gets sent back to the client is up to you to decide. If this is a public API you will never want to send back the raw error but rather a more general response. The error handler puts all your logic for taking care of this in a central place. For example, in our API we log the error to disk together with the request data, session information etc. and a unique ID. The user only sees an "internal error" message with an error ID. The actual stacktrace is never sent to the client.

Comment: Yes. I thought that would happen because I'm sending a custom json string. But entire stack trace is sent. Do you know why?

Comment: Express is probably calling the `toString` method on your `Error` object, causing it to print the entire stacktrace. Which is similar to what would happen if you write the error to a logfile.

Comment: No matter what I try to send as in response, the output I receive does not change.

Comment: Can you show me your code (or at least the relevant parts)?

Comment: I have made code changes. Can you please check now?

Comment: Looks OK at first sight. Do you still have a problem?

Comment: I expect a json with error key and message. But it doesnt give that json object. It gives Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column ....<more error trace> when there is an error only

Answer (score 2):

In plain NodeJS, instead of `throw`ing an error, you could do something like:

```
app.connection.query('UPDATE ITEMS.ITEMS_TABLE SET item_isdeleted=1 WHERE id=' + req.query.item_id,
  function(err, rows){
    if(err){
      console.log('error occured in deleting: code - ' + err.code + " ,isFatal - " + err.fatal);

      // Send error message with status as "failure" or smth explanatory
      res.send({"status": "failure", "message": 'error occured in deleting: code - ' + err.code + " ,isFatal - " + err.fatal });
    } else {
      res.send({"status": "success", "message": "Item deleted with id - " + req.query.item_id });
    }
});
```

Comment: If I send a response it would again crash saying that response headers can't be set.